# Why are Cordova tools not available on Visual Studio for Mac Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-mac

Hello, I have downloaded and installed Visual Studio for Mac Community edition for developing Cordova based cross-platform Apps. But I could not find any option to install Cordova within the VS. You can click the link to view the screenshot during the installation of VS. Generally, VS shows a list of components to download but as you can see in the image, there is no option to install Cordova.
[Visual Studio Installation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72hnp.png) I have attached the screenshot of the Installation. So you can click on the link to view it.

So, Do let me know if I can get Cordova installed on this VS or not?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `TACO` is only supported (currently) on Visual Studio for Windows, you can connect to  macOS to build iOS Cordova apps from Windows:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide

Comment: Ok, Thank you (: